# What will be an XPath of element containing "9"?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath, ui-automation

What will be a correct XPath for locating "9" from line "09 Some text"?

```
<div class="callout" data-testid="callout" xpath="1">
    <span class="container" data-testid="callout" xpath="1">
    </span>
    <p xpath="1">"Some text"</p>
   "Some text1"
   "09 Some text"
   "Some text3"
</div>
```

[image]

I've tried the 3 locators below and I can locate element "9" from Chrome "Find by XPath" but when I use these in an automation script (Selenium WebDriver, C#m and specflow), they don't work.

```
IsElementDisplayed(By.XPath("xpath below"));
```

1. `//div[contains(@class,'callout')]/descendant::text()[contains(., '9')]`
2. `//div[contains(@class, 'callout')]//text()[contains(normalize-space(.), '9')]`
3. `//div[contains(@class,'callout')]//text()[contains(., '9')]`

This one below doesnt work in both (Chrome "Find by xpath" / automation script)

```
//div[contains(@class, 'callout')]//*[contains(text(), '9')]
```

Comment: @SirRufo Thanks... sorry, I didn't mean to slam over your edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use an XPath to return just a string/text in Selenium. For example, if you use the XPath

```
//div[@class='callout']/text()
```

it throws

```
Exception has occurred: InvalidSelectorException
Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//div[@class='callout']/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
```

You CAN use a CSS selector

```
div.callout
```

and it returns the entire block of text inside the DIV

```
"\"Some text\"\r\n\"Some text1\" \"09 Some text\" \"Some text3\""
```

Then you can parse that down to the line you want.

```
string allText = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.callout")).Text;
string text = allText.Split('"').Where(w => w.StartsWith("09")).ToArray().First();
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

which prints

```
09 Some text
```

Comment: Thanks @JeffC, using CSS selector to get text worked, but this one doesnt work (string text) but I guess it doesnt get split well but I used Contains to find if it contains "9" and it works great, thanks :) 

var lastDate = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[class*='callout']")).Text;
var isLastDateCorrect = lastDate.Contains("9");
Assert.IsTrue(isLastDateCorrect, "Last date is incorrect");

Comment: Put that new info into a new question with all the relevant info and we can take a look. I'm guessing it can be solved as well but I can't do that without all the other necessary info.